# MySQL generating more rows than there is

Tags: mysql

Can I do this in mysql

Have this table

```
id | uid | n_unpaid_debt | n_debts | start_date
1  | 1   | 4             | 6       | some date
```

there is 4 unpaid debts and there is a total of 6 
so the first and second month have been paid

I want to generate something like

```
id | uid | some date + 3 month
id | uid | some date + 4 month
id | uid | some date + 5 month
id | uid | some date + 6 month
```

can this be done in SQL ?

Comment: Short answer: Yes (maybe not a simple way, but it can be done). [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: whatever you're asking, i'm pretty sure it can be done, but i'm not sure what you're asking - what are your results based on?  4 rows because of 4 unpaid debts?  how do you know which months?

Comment: debts are always paid on the earliest month that it hasn't been paid, and yes 4 rows b/c 4 unpaid debts

Comment: This idea is totally new to me, I haven't encounter before a way to generate more rows than there is... So i am trying to change the php part instead of the sql but if it can be done on sql then it saves a lot of hassle

Answer (score 0):

If the number of unpaid_debt is limited (e.g. 12 or 24 months max or even 100 months), you can define a second table with id = 1,2,3,4,5... Then join the main table with table_2 with condition "... WHERE table_2.id <= n_unpaid_debt". E.g:

SELECT t1.id, t1.uid, DATE_ADD(t1.start_date, INTERVAL t2.id MONTH) FROM table_1 t1, table_2 t2 WHERE t2.id <= t1.n_unpaid_debt;

Comment: This solution seems redundant. Not really what I am looking for. It's better to do it in php than doing that

Comment: @Rmxhaha if you *can* do it in your front end, I think it's a better idea than trying to do it with "pure" sql

Comment: If something can be done in SQL (without using cursors or similar loops), I always prefer it. However, it depends on personal preference.